# ARMCC 5 optimization of strtol and strtod

Tags: c, arm, keil

I have a board based on STM32L4 MCU (Ultra Low Power Cortex-M4) for GNSS tracking purposes. I don't use RTOS, so I use a custom scheduler. Compiler and environment is KEIL uVision 5 (compiler 5.05 and 5.06, behavior doesn't change)

The MCU speaks with GNSS module via plain UART and the protocol is a mix of NMEA and AT. GNSS position is given as plain text that must be converted to a pair of float/double coordinates.
To get the double/float value from text, I use strtod (or strtof).
Note that string operations are made in a separate buffer, different from the UART RX one.

The typical string for a latitude on the UART is

4256.45783

which means 42° 56.45783'

to get absolute position in degrees, I use the following formula

42 + 56.45783 / 60

When there is no optimization the code works fine and the position is converted right. When I turn on level 1 optimization (or higher), if I use standard C library I can convert the integer part (42 in the example) and when it comes to convert 56.45783, I get only 56 (so the integer part of minutes until the dot).

If I get rid of standard library and I use a custom strtod function downloaded from ANSI C source library I simply get 0 with ERANGE error.

In other parts of the code I use strtol, which has a strange behavior when L1 optimization is turned ON: when the first digit is 9 and conversion base is 10 it simply skips that 9 going on with the other digits.

So if in the buffer I have 92, I will get just 2 parsed. To get rid of this I simply prepended a sign + to the number and the result is always OK (as far as I can tell). This WA doesn't work with strtod.

Note that I tried to use static, volatile and on-stack variables, behavior doesn't change.

EDIT: I simplified the code in order to get where it goes wrong, as per comments hereafter

C code is like this:

```
void GnssStringToLatLonDegMin(const char* str, LatLong_t* struc)
{
    double dbl = 0.0;
    dbl = strtod("56.45783",NULL);
    if(struc != NULL)
    {
        struc->Axis = (float)((dbl / 60.0) + 42.0);
    }
}
```

Level 0 optimization:

```
559: void GnssStringToLatLonDegMin(const char* str, LatLong_t* struc) 
0x08011FEE BDF8      POP           {r3-r7,pc}
560: { 
0x08011FF0 B570      PUSH          {r4-r6,lr}
0x08011FF2 4605      MOV           r5,r0
0x08011FF4 ED2D8B06  VPUSH.64      {d8-d10}
0x08011FF8 460C      MOV           r4,r1
561:         double dbl = 0.0; 
0x08011FFA ED9F0BF8  VLDR          d0,[pc,#0x3E0]
0x08011FFE EEB08A40  VMOV.F32      s16,s0
0x08012002 EEF08A60  VMOV.F32      s17,s1
562:         dbl = strtod("56.45783",NULL); 
0x08012006 2100      MOVS          r1,#0x00 
0x08012008 A0F6      ADR           r0,{pc}+4  ; @0x080123E4
0x0801200A F7FDFED1  BL.W          __hardfp_strtod (0x0800FDB0)
0x0801200E EEB08A40  VMOV.F32      s16,s0 
0x08012012 EEF08A60  VMOV.F32      s17,s1
563:         if(struc != NULL) 
564:         { 
0x08012016 B1A4      CBZ           r4,0x08012042
565:                 struc->Axis = (float)((dbl / 60.0) + 42.0); 
566:         } 
0x08012018 ED9F0BF5  VLDR          d0,[pc,#0x3D4]
0x0801201C EC510B18  VMOV          r0,r1,d8
0x08012020 EC532B10  VMOV          r2,r3,d0
0x08012024 F7FEF880  BL.W          __aeabi_ddiv (0x08010128)
0x08012028 EC410B1A  VMOV          d10,r0,r1
0x0801202C ED9F0BF2  VLDR          d0,[pc,#0x3C8]
0x08012030 EC532B10  VMOV          r2,r3,d0
0x08012034 F7FDFFBC  BL.W          __aeabi_dadd (0x0800FFB0)
0x08012038 EC410B19  VMOV          d9,r0,r1
0x0801203C F7FDFF86  BL.W          __aeabi_d2f (0x0800FF4C)
0x08012040 6020      STR           r0,[r4,#0x00]
567: }
```

LEVEL 1 optimization

```
557: void GnssStringToLatLonDegMin(const char* str, LatLong_t* struc) 
0x08011FEE BDF8      POP           {r3-r7,pc}
558: { 
559:         double dbl = 0.0; 
0x08011FF0 B510      PUSH          {r4,lr}
0x08011FF2 460C      MOV           r4,r1
560:         dbl = strtod("56.45783",NULL); 
0x08011FF4 2100      MOVS          r1,#0x00
0x08011FF6 A0F7      ADR           r0,{pc}+2  ; @0x080123D4
0x08011FF8 F7FDFEDA  BL.W          __hardfp_strtod (0x0800FDB0)
561:         if(struc != NULL) 
562:         { 
0x08011FFC 2C00      CMP           r4,#0x00
0x08011FFE D010      BEQ           0x08012022
563:                 struc->Axis = (float)((dbl / 60.0) + 42.0); 
564:         } 
0x08012000 ED9F1BF7  VLDR          d1,[pc,#0x3DC]
0x08012004 EC510B10  VMOV          r0,r1,d0
0x08012008 EC532B11  VMOV          r2,r3,d1
0x0801200C F7FEF88C  BL.W          __aeabi_ddiv (0x08010128)
0x08012010 ED9F1BF5  VLDR          d1,[pc,#0x3D4]
0x08012014 EC532B11  VMOV          r2,r3,d1
0x08012018 F7FDFFCA  BL.W          __aeabi_dadd (0x0800FFB0)
0x0801201C F7FDFF96  BL.W          __aeabi_d2f (0x0800FF4C)
0x08012020 6020      STR           r0,[r4,#0x00]
565: }
```

I looked at the disassembly of __hardfp_strtod and __strtod_int called by these functions and, as they are incorporated as binaries, they don't change with respect of optimization level.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger, to make sure there's not something else wrong in your parsing?

Comment: Does `tmpf = strtod("56.45783",NULL);` work?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, sure... that's why I posted the question... the buffer is correct (as far as I can see from the debugger)

Comment: @MichaelBurr, thanks. I will try and let you know...

Comment: Please show how you call `GnssStringToLatLonDegMin`.

Comment: Can you reproduce this behaviour iin a simple, self-contained piece of code?

Comment: you could just avoid strod in the first place walk through the characters converting them as you go (accumulator times 10 add new value (byte&0xF), when you hit the decimal point do another conversion now you have both halves, when you hit the comma you are done (parsing) some simple math should then convert the halves into what you are after.

Comment: what is the raw string you are parsing?

Comment: basically do you really feel you need a C library for a cortex-m for this work (strtok is scary at best anyway at any time on any platform, and strtod is more overhead being generic since you know what you are after)

Comment: This probably doesn't have anything to do with the problem being asked about, but it looks like `strncpy(line, orig_line, linelen)` could leave `line` without a null terminator.

Comment: @old_timer Thanks a lot for your hint. I will make my strtod following your algorithm. If you post it as an answer I will surely upvote that.

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: @old_timer I will let you know later.

Comment: @old_timer Thank you, it worked perfectly. Check out the code in the edit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to optimization, strtod didn't work.
Thanks to @old_timer, I had to make my own strtod function, which works even with optimization level set at level 2.

```
double simple_strtod(const char* str)
{
 int8 inc;
 double result = 0.0;
 char * c_tmp;
 c_tmp = strchr(str, '.');
 if(c_tmp != NULL)
 {
    c_tmp++;
    inc = -1;
    while(*c_tmp != 0 && inc > -9)
    {
        result += (*c_tmp - '0') * pow(10.0, inc);
        c_tmp++; inc--;
    }
    inc = 0;
    c_tmp = strchr(str, '.');
    c_tmp--;
    do
    {
        result += (*c_tmp - '0') * pow(10.0,inc);
        c_tmp--; inc++;
    }while(c_tmp >= str);
 }
 return result; 
}
```

It can be further optimized by not calling 'pow' and use something more clever, but just like this it works perfectly.